# Grabbing JSON and parsing to a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So currently i'm using PHP to grab a price from a JSON file off my server. I feel this would be a a lot better to use if I switched over to javascript. I'm a little bit confused on using JSON.Stringify(), and even if it would work in this situation. Here is the current code that I use to grab JSON objects, and display them on the page:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxxxxx.com/foo.json');
$list = json_decode($json);
$value = 'value';
$case = 'The Powerhouse Weapons Case';
$casem = $list->response->items->$case->$value;
$casef = money_format('$%i', ($casem/ 100));
echo $casef;
```

What would be the best way to do this in Javscript?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but what is your question?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts an object to a JSON string. `JSON.parse` converts a JSON string into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pure Javascript to get that file and then parse it.

Take a look at this [Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

It would be something like this:

```
function reqListener () {
  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var value = json.response.items['The Powerhouse Weapons Case'].value;
  var formattedValue = '$' + Number(value / 100).toFixed(2);
  console.log(formattedValue);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/foo.json");
oReq.send();
```

`JSON.parse()` is the equivalent of `json_decode()` in PHP.

I don't know how the json file looks like so I copied references from your php code.

Also, I used `console.log()` function to display your formatted value, but you can, of course, do with it whatever you want.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for the help man, I can't wait to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

If your object already is json, just itterate it, not stringify it. If its an object you can acces the properties almost the same only it would be list.response.items.case.value